# Will there be Ubuntu compatibility with AMD CPU / Processor: Samsung Exynos 5 Dual soon?

Tags: ati, samsung, chromebook

Will there be Ubuntu compatibility with AMD CPU / Processor: Samsung Exynos 5 Dual soon? I realize the Chromebook is recently out, but I would appreciate knowing if it's in the works.